# send data from Android app to local server

Tags: php, android

i want to send data from android application to local server (PHP) but it doesn't work 
this is my code (it is work with remote server ):

```
        String path ="http://localhost/sd.php";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

        HttpResponse response;

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);

            json.put("im", 999);
            json.put("cTime", 12);
            Log.i("jason Object", json.toString());
            post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);

            response = client.execute(post);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Object n=e.getStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),n.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

i thing the wrong in the address `http://localhost/sd.php`
pleas help me to find a solution to this problem

Comment: I guess by "local" you mean "on the emulator's host machine"... That won't be "local" on a real phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the IP address of the server.  Localhost from the app is the phone.

Comment: How can i get the IP address of the server(it is local server)?

Comment: On the server type ifconfig if using a Mac or Unix box.  ipconfig in Windows.